# How do I carry out conditional arguments for a function in R with different inputs from the user for one of the variables in the function?

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I want to create a function in R as so:

```
PPAFunction <- function(Point_data, Shape_file, CRS, Type)
```

with the final parameter "Type" having 3 options (options that I specify in the manual I provide) and each option carries out a different argument with the other three given parameters. Not sure how I go about coding it but here is the general gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
if(Type = x)
#carry out argument

else if (Type = y)
# carry out argument

if(Type = z)
#carry out argument
```

The error code that I am getting is:

> Error: unexpected '=' in: "PPAFunction <- function(Point_data, Shape_file, CRS, Type){if (Type ="

So I'm guessing there's something wrong with the formatting of my if statements.

Comment: You need `if(Type == x)` instead of `=`

Comment: thank you so much akrun, feel kinda dumb for not thinking of this